# Launching chrome browser application with desktop view in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, automation, appium

I am launching chrome app using the following desired capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.ChromeTabbedActivity");
    capabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
    driverC = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

I wish to know the capabilities required to launch chrome app with Request desktop site check box enabled.

Screen for referrence:

[image]

Comment: Venkatesh G Did you found any answers for this scenario?

Comment: Didn't find any @AshokkumarGanesan

Comment: I tried the below one and it got worked

Answer (score 1):

In Mobile automation, to automate the browser in Desktop mode we can perform with the help of **user-agent**.

**Steps to follow:**

1. Find the user agent for your device and browser. In your device/emulator navigate to the [find my user agent](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) website and it automatically displays the user agent as below. (make a note of it)

   [image: Find user agent]
2. Add the above user agent to the **ChromeOptions** with the help of *--user-agent* flag. Then assign the flag option with the desired capabilities as below.

   *On the user agent you can add all the browsers OR the one you wanted to automate.*

   **CODE:**

   ```
   DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.0");
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Nexus_10");                
   caps.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","\\driver\\chromedriver_74.exe");
   caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "chrome");
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.addArguments("--user-agent=Chrome/74.0.3729.185");
   caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   url = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
   driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(url), caps);
   ```
3. Now run the program and verify the execution. The browser automatically opens in desktop mode on the automation device.

*(This was performed with the Java language and similar approach could be performed with the other languages)*