# Open website in desktop view by default in selenium automation

Tags: selenium, mobile, automation

Am trying to automate a website in mobile which is not a responsive site. Challenge what am facing is some menus getting clicked only if I change the site into Desktop view mode using menu available in chrome options manually. Is there any settings or code available to automate this. I want to make the site as Desktop view by default.
Amusing RemoteDriver

[image]

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
         DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BrowserName,"Chrome");
        caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
        caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "7.1");
        caps.SetCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "ZL33B2YDT5");
         caps.SetCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
        caps.SetCapability("resetKeyboard", true);          
        dr = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        dr.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        dr.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        dr.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
        dr.Navigate().GoToUrl(URL);
        dr.FindElement(By.Id("txtUsername")).SendKeys("su");
        dr.FindElement(By.Id("txtPassword")).SendKeys("sudemo");
        IWebElement login =  dr.FindElement(By.Id("btn_SignIn"));
        Assert.IsTrue(login.Displayed);
        login.Click();
        List<string> lstWindow = dr.WindowHandles.ToList();
        String lastWindowHandle = "";
        foreach (var handle in lstWindow)
        {

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            lastWindowHandle = handle;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        dr.Close();
        dr.SwitchTo().Window(lastWindowHandle);
           //To mouse hover on gen element the site has to be in Desktop view. If its in normal view hover is not happening but if i make site to Desktop View manually hover happening without issue
       string javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                            "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                            "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = dr as IJavaScriptExecutor;

        IWebElement gen = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='rmRootGroup rmRoundedCorners rmShadows rmHorizontal']/li[2]/a //span[contains(text(),'General')]"));
        js.ExecuteScript(javaScript, gen);
         IWebElement group = dr.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[@class='rmRootGroup rmRoundedCorners rmShadows rmHorizontal']/li[2] //ul[@class='rmVertical']/li/a //span[contains(text(),'Group')]"));
        group.Click();
        dr.FindElement(By.LinkText("Logout")).Click();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        dr.Quit();

    }
```

Thanks in advance waiting for your response

Comment: Your code trials please

Comment: I need to open the page in desktop view when driver open website in chrome browser in mobile.Now am giving wait time and clicking it manually on mobile. I need an automated way to do it.

Comment: To mouse hover on gen element the site has to be in Desktop view. If its in normal view hover is not happening but if i make site to Desktop View manually hover happening without issue

Comment: @Deepan Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65616397/4197679